# With Flutter 3.10, which is the better way to get the `Size` with `MediaQuery`

Tags: flutter, performance, dart, mediaquery

Flutter 3.10 has come with several improvements for `MediaQuery` use. And I see that we can for example get the Size using `MediaQuery.of(context).size` as usual, but now we can use `MediaQuery.sizeOf(context)`.

Which is more performant? The latter? Which is the recommendation?

**EDIT (2023-06-15)**: *I'm refining the question. The core of the question is not about getting a `Size`, this is just a simple example of the new ways of using `MediaQuery` new ways of getting the same data using new available methods. That could be with `MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness`-  `MediaQuery.platformBrightnessOf(context)` or another one.*

Comment: If you are only interested in the size changes it is better to use `sizeOf` since it will cause a rebuild only if the size changes. With the old way a rebuild would be triggered upon every change of `MediaQuery`, if I understand right.

Comment: Stop using MediaQuery for size.  Look at LayoutBuilder.

Comment: Randall, I respect your opinion, but yours is not the direct answer to the question, independent that what you're letting us know would be another approach.

Answer (score 3):

After reading some resources, what @peter-koltai shared as a comment is pretty accurate.

Then the answer could be summarized as follow (*Summary taken from Andrea Bizzoto*):

> *By calling `MediaQuery.of(context).size/padding/orientation`, the widget will rebuild when **any** of the MediaQuery properties change
> (less performant). By calling
> `MediaQuery.sizeOf/paddingOf/orientationOf(context)` the widget will
> rebuild **only** when the property changes, avoiding unnecessary
> rebuilds.*

Take a look of this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/114459) where the concept is well explained.